# Implementing advanced search feature with Algolia: has_words, exact_match, and must_contain filters

Tags: python, search, fastapi, algolia

I am currently working on an advanced search feature in a FastAPI application using Algolia. The requirement is to filter search results based on three parameters: has_words, exact_match, and must_contain.

Here is the approach I'm using:

```
algolia_params = {
    "filters": " AND ".join(f'"{word}"' for word in must_contain),
}

if has_words:
    # Not sure how to implement this with Algolia
    pass

if exact_match:
    # Not sure how to implement this with Algolia
    pass

response = index.search("", algolia_params)
```

As you can see, I'm currently stuck on how to implement the has_words and exact_match parameters with Algolia's Python client.

For has_words, I need to return documents that contain at least one of the specified words.
For exact_match, I need to return documents that contain an exact phrase.
If someone could provide guidance on how to implement these filters, or suggest a different approach for achieving advanced search with Algolia, it would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You would need to set `getRankingInfo: true` on your query parameters. This will provide additional information on each of your records response.

It will provide the same information as you can see on the medal icon in the Algolia dashboard.

Source: https://www.algolia.com/doc/api-reference/api-parameters/getRankingInfo/?client=python#examples